# Doubt about current density

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, vectors, classical-electrodynamics

[image: A visualization of what I think about current density]We are taught in electrodynamics classes that current density is a vector quantity while current is a scalar. I understand why current is a scalar and current density is a vector. But what's troubling me is that if current density follows the triangle law of vector addition and if so how? In my figure I think that the sum of the densities at surfaces A and B is equal to the the density at C. Is my thinking correct or what am I missing? Please help in detail.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Current is also a vector.

Comment: All vectors add up like vectors. Otherwise they couldn't be called vectros, they'd be another thing. I don't really understand your statement on the picture actually.

Comment: Why the downvote? May the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since current density is a vector quantity, then yes, if you ever have to add current densities, they will add as vectors.

It just doesn't happen to be particularly common to ever have to add current densities to each other.

One scenario where you might do that is if you have two populations of carriers coexisting in one area of space. For example, two kinds of ionic carriers in a vacuum, or free electrons and ionic carriers in a fluid. And if these two carrier types for some reason are moving in different directions or with different velocities (for example, because they have different masses), then you could find the net current density by summing the current densities due to the two carrier types.

The situations where we often take a sum of currents, for example calculating the net current in and out of a node of a circuit, wouldn't be solved by summing current densities, but by use of the continuity equation

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{j}=-\frac{{\partial}\rho}{\partial t}$$

This says that the divergence of the current density at any point in space is equal to the negative of the time-derivative of charge density at that point.

> In my figure I think that the sum of the densities at surfaces A and B is equal to the the density at C. Is my thinking correct or what am I missing?

No, you don't obtain any meaningful information by summing current densities in this case. There isn't even any reason to believe *a priori* that the current density is constant over the whole area of surface A or surface B or surface C. It could be varying as an arbitrary function of position.

The rule you could derive related to conservation of charge in this scenario is

$$\iint_A \vec{j}\cdot\hat{\bf n}\ dS + \iint_B \vec{j}\cdot\hat{\bf n}\ dS = \iint_C \vec{j}\cdot\hat{\bf n}\ dS$$

If you had some way to know that the current density is constant over each of these surfaces (and that all the current flowing through surfaces A and B also flows through C), then you could simplify the equation to

$$ A|\vec{j}|\cos\phi_A + B|\vec{j}|\cos\phi_B = C|\vec{j}|\cos\phi_C$$

where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the areas of the three surfaces, and $\phi_A$, $\phi_B$ and $\phi_C$ are the angles between the current density and the surface normals.

This would in some sense be "summing the current densities", but only after scaling by the amount of area covered by each surface and accounting for the angles of the surface --- which is really how you would calculate the macroscopic current $J$ through each of the surfaces. So what you've really come up with is just

$$J_A + J_B = J_C.$$

Comment: Imagine a metallic cylinder of diameter d with its axis along the x axis, carrying current along the same mentioned direction. Now if we consider a plane making 30 degrees with the xy plane that cuts through the cylinder and stops where it meets the xy plane and similarly, a plane making -30 degrees with the xy plane that cuts through the cylinder and stops where it meets the xy plane. Can we say that the sum of the current densities through those planes equals that at a plane at that point that is normal to the xy plane and parallel to the z axis?

Comment: @user8718165, Current density is an [intensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties), not extensive. For your scenario you 'd want to take the integral of the current density (probably dotted with the unit vector normal to each surface) over the different surfaces and compare.

Comment: Would you mind telling me a little more?Any suggestion is of great help to me

Comment: More about what? I tried to answer the question you posted as best I could. If you have a new question or a follow up question, you can click "Ask a question" to ask it.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what i think. I didn't fully get your second last comment so could you please clarify and help me a little more.Any suggestion is of great help to me.

Comment: @ThePhoton Please edit your first equation. The derivative should be
$\partial\rho/\partial t$.

Comment: In the third equation why is $\sin \phi_A$, $\sin \phi_B$ , $\sin \phi_C$ used?Shouldn't $cosines$ be used instead as we're dealing with dot products over here? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user8718165, yes, they should be cosines. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> We are taught in electrodynamics classes that current density is a vector quantity while current is a scalar. I understand why current is a scalar and current density is a vector.

Current isn't actually a vector quantity, this is an artifact of history in that Gibbs & Heaviside promoted the use of vectors to understand electromagnetism. Maxwell originally wrote his equations with quaternions.

This can be seen by looking at electromagnetism in more than four dimensions and analysing the kind of structures that make it possible to write down Maxwells equations. It turns out that two of them are purely topological, in the sense that no metric is used and the other two require a metric. Moreover rather than being seen as vectors - a directed magnitude - they're better seen in the light of a generalisation - orientated line segments, area parallelograms and volume parallelopids.

Its because of the metric and the fact that space is 3d that we can convert area elements and volume elements into vectors.